# This below statement gives me #Value!. I dont know where Iam going wrong

Tags: vba, excel

I dont know where Iam going wrong. I have tried using ' to format the cell type but it dint help.

`aCopyTo.Range("B4:G4").Value = [{"LAT"},{"LONG"},{"VERT"},{"ISO"},{"ROLL"},{"PITCH"}]`

I want to add these values to the cells in the range B4:G4. Please Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign an array if it's to cells in the same row:

```
aCopyTo.Range("B4:G4").Value = Array("LAT", "LONG", "VERT", "ISO", "ROLL", "PITCH")
```

If it's a column, then transpose the array:

```
aCopyTo.Range("B4:B9").Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Array("LAT", "LONG", "VERT", "ISO", "ROLL", "PITCH"))
```